# Chrome / Safari HTML5 Video Fullscreen Mode not working properly

Tags: javascript, css, html, google-chrome

I've implemented the Video.js player into my site, however there is a slight problem with Chrome and Safari. The parents of the video player have a `position relative` attribute attached to them and thus the full screen mode will align the video to the left and to the top of its parent. Just as if I were to set the video player to `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;`. This only happens in Chrome and Safari, however not in Firefox. Has anyone come across this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that the container has a **keyframe animation** and that ended up being the problem! I had a fadeIn animation which loads by default and that apparently caused the problem. By removing the `animation` attribute, it begun working in safari and in chrome. I am not sure why, unfortunately.